# passing value dynamically to the JASPER API to generate a Report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am generating the Report using the Jasper Reports .
Inside the JRXML file in queryString  , the query that is formed is

```
 SELECT * FROM Address WHERE city = $P{customerId}
```

Now inside my servlet please tell me how can i pass this value dynamically ??

```
int custid  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("customerId")) ;

Map parameters = new HashMap();

parameters.put("customerId", custid);
```

Please tell me is this the correct way of passing the data ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own datasource (must be [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) interface implementation).

After filling (preparing) datasource it should be passed to the [JasperFillManager.fillReport(java.lang.String sourceFileName, java.util.Map parameters, JRDataSource jrDataSource)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperManager.html#fillReport%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29) method.

The sample:

```java
    JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(data);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(sourceFileName, paramsMap, dataSource);
```